# can't estimateGas error upon calling provider.getSigner(); using etherjs 5.7 and metamask provider

Tags: javascript, web3js, metamask, ethers.js

```js
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any");
const accounts = await provider.listAccounts()
console.log(await provider.getBalance(accounts[0]));
const signer = provider.getSigner();
```

Here's the code; (this is wrapped inside an async func)

Here's the error I receive when the debugger reaches "Signer"

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="execution reverted", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xE0462A44f97421E0A896cb2A7A31624D592ea52F","to":"0x7810ee6cbe9d0DB24d86110115A88d1200844DFd","data":"0x8632d6ed0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","accessList":null}, error={"code":-32603,"message":"execution reverted","data":{"originalError":{"code":3,"data":"0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011","message":"execution reverted"}}}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.7.2)
```

It was working quite fine last night but something happened and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Your gas estimation fail because your call reverted when executing.

the error message is:

```
{
    "code": -32603,
    "message": "execution reverted",
    "data": {
        "originalError": {
            "code": 3,
            "data": "0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011",
            "message": "execution reverted"
        }
    }
}
```

the error message `0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011` decodes to `Panic(17)`

More info is needed for the contract `0x7810ee6cbe9d0DB24d86110115A88d1200844DFd` you are calling.